# format output of unix `bc` utility

Tags: unix, bc

For large outputs `bc` utility in unix gives output in this format:

```shellsession
$ bc
bc 1.06.95 Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.     
2^1000
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703\
51051124936122493198378815695858127594672917553146825187145285692314\
04359845775746985748039345677748242309854210746050623711418779541821\
53046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660\
429831652624386837205668069376
```

Is it possible to add formatting options so that it give the output in just 1 line

Comment: My `bc` doesn't do that. What operation did you perform to get that output? And what version of `bc`?

Comment: `$ bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
2^1000
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703\
51051124936122493198378815695858127594672917553146825187145285692314\
04359845775746985748039345677748242309854210746050623711418779541821\
53046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660\
429831652624386837205668069376`

Comment: Ah those numbers are a lot longer than your example. Mine does that, too.

Comment: I will modify the question to reflect a valid case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the `BC_LINE_LENGTH` environment variable as [documented here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC23).